# How update infinite scroll js

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I this error when un tried after destroy infiniteScroll object, to init new instance :

> main.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: o._init is not a function

In my ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
  url : $('form').attr('action'), 
  data: $('form').serialize(),
  type: 'GET',
  encode: 1,
  success: function(reponseHTML){
     $('.products').infiniteScroll('destroy');

     $('.products').infiniteScroll({
        path: '.next a',
        append: '.product-wrapper',
        history: true,
      });
   }});
```

I follow the official documentation of the plugin :
https://infinite-scroll.com/api.html

Comment: Did you tried to setup timeout?

Comment: Did you try to add a try-catch block to the destroy call? Maybe the infinite scroll instance can't be destroyed if it wasn't created yet. Is there a way to check if the element was used for the infinite scroll plugin?

Answer (score 0):

after destroy call, I remove DOM Element of infinite Scroll.

```
$('.product').remove();
```

to recreate them with reponseHTML. 
:) 
Thx,